# Problems to detect arrays in JSON files using YAJL trees in C

Tags: c, arrays, json, yajl

I try to parse a JSON file using yajl 2.0.4 (using yajl_tree.h) but I have some problems to detect whether the found value is an array or not (even if I use YAJL_IS_ARRAY, it seems that the type field is not set.

Here is my JSON file :

```
{
    "equipment": [
        {
            "name": "mynode",
            "type": "node",
            "attribute": [
                {
                    "name": "cpu_available",
                    "value": "8"
                },
                {
                    "name": "memory_available",
                    "value": "24"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my code :

```
const char *path[] = { "equipment", (const char *) 0 };
yajl_val v = yajl_tree_get( node, path, yajl_t_array );
if ( v && YAJL_IS_ARRAY( v ) ) {
    for ( i = 0; i < v->u.array.len; i++ ) {
        yajl_val obj = v->u.array.values[i];
        if( obj && YAJL_IS_ARRAY(obj)) {
            for ( j = 0; j < obj->u.object.len; j++ ) {
                yajl_val obj2 = obj->u.array.values[ j ];
                if(obj2 && YAJL_IS_ARRAY(obj2)) {
                    for ( k = 0; k < obj2->u.array.len; k++ ) {
                        yajl_val obj3 = obj->u.array.values[ k ];
                        const char * key3 = obj3->u.object.keys[ k ];
                        yajl_val val3 = obj3->u.object.values[ k ];
                            printf( "      %s : %s \n", key3, val3->u.string );
                    }
                }
                else {
                    const char * key2 = obj->u.object.keys[ j ];
                    yajl_val val2 = obj->u.object.values[ j ];
                        printf( "    %s : %s \n", key2, val2->u.string );
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            const char * key = obj->u.object.keys[ i ];
            yajl_val val = obj->u.object.values[ i ];
                printf( "  %s : %s ", key, val->u.string );
        }
    }
}
```

When I use this code I never enter the YAJL_IS_ARRAY even if the value is an array, for example attribute. So I was wondering if YAJL_IS_ARRAY is not correct to get an array, what must be used ?  Moreover, is it normal that the type of my objects (obj, obj2...) have no correct types ? What mistake did I do ?

Thanks in advance for your help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON isn't an array. It's a dictionary with a key "equipment", and the value of "equipment" is an array. In this case, an array containing a single dictionary.

Comment: Thanks ! :) I had a confusion between arrays and objects.